# Accounting for time with repeated-measures in lmer

Tags: time-series, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I am trying to conduct a repeated-measures mixed-effects test with lmer and lmerTest, but I am not sure if I am doing it appropriately.

I have 6 sites with 3 plots per site that have been sampled once per year for 24 consecutive years. I have several environmental and species variables, but for simplicity, let's say I have two environmental variables (depth and temperature) and two species (species 1 and species 2). I am not interested in the time variable, changes with time, or the interactions, as this system has strong wet/dry seasonality where the effects of the dry season outweigh carry over effects of species from the prior year. I do not necessarily have data for all variables and plots every year, with some plots not sampled at times.

The question is whether species2 (a predator) has any effect on populations of species1, relative to the environmental variables.

Is it appropriate to include year as its own random effect in the model, along with plot within site?

```
model1 <- lmer(species1 ~ depth + temperature +  species2 + (1|year) + (1|site/plot), data=data)
```

For this particular analysis, there were 435 total observations (plot/year), but I worry that it is not appropriately conducting repeated-measures.

```
anova(model1)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
               Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
depth          0.0221  0.0221     1 145.75  0.0908    0.7635    
temperature    9.0213  9.0213     1 422.19 37.0429 2.596e-09 ***
species2       0.0597  0.0597     1 418.95  0.2450    0.6208 

summary(model1)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: species1 ~ depth + temperature + species2 + (1 | YEAR) + (1 | site/plot)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   726.9    759.5   -355.4    710.9      427 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3350 -0.6432 -0.1166  0.5818  3.0199 

Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 year             (Intercept) 0.163255 0.40405 
 plot:site        (Intercept) 0.005273 0.07262 
 site             (Intercept) 0.265475 0.51524 
 Residual                     0.243535 0.49349 
Number of obs: 435, groups:  year, 24; plot:site, 24; site, 6

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.588186   0.390005  54.003413   1.508    0.137    
depth                0.001295   0.004295 145.746531   0.301    0.764    
temperature          0.214137   0.035183 422.190727   6.086  2.6e-09 ***
species2            -0.105709   0.213547 418.949883  -0.495    0.621    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) depth  temp
depth       -0.489              
temperature -0.385 -0.224       
species2    -0.391 -0.024  0.005
```

Is this ok? Is the a better way to incorporate year, or should I include year at all?

If I exclude year, why does the DenDF for depth change so drastically?

```
model1 <- lmer(species1 ~ depth + temperature +  species2 + (1|year) + (1|site/plot), data=data)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
               Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF  F value    Pr(>F)    
depth          2.599   2.599     1 431.77   7.1096  0.007955 ** 
temperature    58.788  58.788    1 432.10 160.7955 < 2.2e-16 ***
species2       0.853   0.853     1 429.62   2.3336  0.127343    

summary(M1)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: species1 ~ depth + temperature + species2 + (1 | site/plot)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   833.4    861.9   -409.7    819.4      428 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.20675 -0.66119 -0.07051  0.52722  2.99942 

Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 plot:site        (Intercept) 0.0003221 0.01795 
 site             (Intercept) 0.2051143 0.45290 
 Residual                     0.3656072 0.60465 
Number of obs: 435, groups:  plot:site, 24; site, 6

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         -0.538258   0.325072  50.071940  -1.656  0.10401    
depth                0.006338   0.002377 431.768539   2.666  0.00796 ** 
temperature          0.391023   0.030837 432.101095  12.681  < 2e-16 ***
species2            -0.353264   0.231252 429.615226  -1.528  0.12734    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) depth  temp
depth       -0.316              
temperature -0.467 -0.204       
specie2     -0.544  0.040  0.007
```

Comment: What research questions are you trying to answer from this analysis please ?

Comment: Also, you say you sample *"once per year for 24 consecutive years"* but then you have `(1|year)` which doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you could also include the full output of the model from `summary(model1)`

Comment: @RobertLong I updated the question with what you asked about